# Windows Scripting: What and How to do this? Batch Files or Something else?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, windows

What I am trying to do is have some sort of script run in windows (ideally .cmd file/batch file) when double clicked it should create a short-cut menu in the start menu and set a path in the windows registry (i think thats what it is called) so that next time, for example, all I have to is get the variable JAVA_HOME to get the path I need.

What I need help in this is just examples on how to do these, what tutorials I should look at or even what key terms to search in Google (seriously) as I am very new to windows programming and what's used for what etc.

Thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to target *all* versions of Windows, your best choice is writing a **MS-DOS Batch** file (*.bat*). Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.allenware.com/icsw/icswidx.htm) that I've used in the past.

If you are targeting *modern* versions of Windows (Windows XP SP2/2003/Vista/7) you should definitely take a look at **[Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx)**, which is the new standard automation engine for the Windows platform.
PowerShell is a [separate download](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx) for Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 and Windows Vista, while it is included in Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.

**About Windows PowerShell**
PowerShell is built on top of the .NET Framework and consists of a **runtime environment**, a **scripting language** and an **interactive console**.
Here are *some* of its key features that I find most valuable:

- All processing is done using CLR objects, instead of text as in traditional shells
- It is possible to interact directly with the classes in the .NET Framework
- It is possible to run commands written in any .NET language and distributed as DLLs (called *Cmdlets*)
- Great collection of built-in commands to accomplish most administrative tasks
- The scripting language's syntax is C-style (curly braces...)
- The runtime can be hosted inside any managed process as an *ad-hoc* automation engine

This isn't of course a complete list of all the features in PowerShell. If you are interested, I recommend you to look into it. Here is [a good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714418(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: +1 for PowerShell, although a link to a good tutorial would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am guessing what can be done on bat files can be done on the PowerShell? Or can one do more?

Comment: PowerShell can do a lot more than most shells, especially the MS-DOS emulator ;-) I updated my answer with some more details about PowerShell.

Comment: A nice compromise is VBScript, which is already present on Windows 2000 and later. It's more robust than batch scripting, but more available than Powershell.

Comment: @Jason: You're absolutely right. I forgot about the Windows Script Host (WSH), which supports scripting in VBScript and JScript and allows to interact with COM/ActiveX objects. In that regard it is the predecessor of PowerShell.